# Is gradle installed with Android Studio on Windows?

Tags: android-studio, cordova, gradle

I'm on Windows 10 and I have Android Studio installed and a version of the SDK installed. If I wish to use gradle on my command line(I'm running `cordova requirement`), how do I find out the path of gradle? If gradle is installed together with Android Studio that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio installs Gradle in a folder that looks like:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\bin
```

Please note that "7.0.2" is the gradle version, and this number may be different for you.

Find this path in you computer and add it to Windows "Path" environment variable. On Start Menu, type "environment variable", select "Path", click on "Edit" and add the gradle path to the list.

Restart "Command Prompt" (or PowerShell) before running `cordova requirements` again.